# Unable to get working ManyToOne ApiSubresource relaction. Error: StateFieldPathExpression or SingleValuedAssociationField expected

Tags: php, symfony, api-platform.com

I have started make a small project on API Platform to check it how it works.

Unfortunately at the very start I came to a problem that I cannot make `@ApiSubresource` `ManyToOne` relation because it throws an error

> "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 129 near 'users = :cur': Error:
>   Invalid PathExpression. StateFieldPathExpression or
>   SingleValuedAssociationField expected."

My classes looks like that:

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource(
 *     collectionOperations={"post"},
 *     itemOperations={
 *     "get"={ "security"="is_granted('VIEW_AS_OWNER_USER', object)", }
 *     },
 *     normalizationContext={"groups"={"operation:read"}},
 *     denormalizationContext={"groups"={"operation:write"}}
 * )
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="`user`")
 */
class User implements UserInterface
{
    /* rest of the entity declaration omitted */
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Band", inversedBy="users")
     * @ApiSubresource()
     */
    private $band;
}
```

```php
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\BandRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="band")
 */
class Band
{
    /* rest of the entity declaration omitted */

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", mappedBy="band")
     */
    private $users;

}
```

After digging inside Symfony Parser it looks like it tries to execute this SQL:

> SELECT o FROM App\Entity\Band o WHERE o IN(SELECT IDENTITY(id_a1.band) FROM App\Entity\User id_a1 WHERE id_a1.id = :id_p1) AND o.users = :current_user

With these two parameters:
[image]

I have found some advices, but every one was for Symfony for manual query. There is some automatic query building at, at least for me, very basic level.

Do you know what I have done wrong? Or it is just broken framework?

Comment: I have checked if it is all about UUID identifier, but no, when i change it to integer the same exception occurs

Comment: I have also created bug report there: https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1513

Comment: I have started project from scratch and use just autoincrement id without UUID and it seems that it is working well, but anyway it can be a problem for someone who want to use UUID.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a good idea to use an UUID as primary key. All comparaisons done by your database will take a longer time to compare string than integer, so joins will be less efficient. You should have an integer as primary key. UUID is used to avoid that someone tries URL by changing id and testing all id. Then, you can simply use uuid as another property. You only have to set the Api-property `identifier` to true, and API-Platform will use it instead of primary key. This advise could perhaps fix your problem, but I'm not sure.

I think you should wait that API-Platform team merges [this pull-request](https://github.com/api-platform/core/pull/3529)

Doctrine use sequence to generate autoincrementation. So database will never try to insert two records having the same auto-increment key. Sequence had been created to avoid this problem.

UUID are a small performance issue if you add an index and if you only searching your entity via this uuid. If you do something else, like a inner join with another entity, it will be a big performance issue.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! What about parallel saving into database? Using auto-increment you are making yourself  dependent on database implementation. I heard opinion (to be hones i haven't checked it) that in some situation database can try to insert two records having the same auto-increment key. This is why i decided to depend on UUID.   Is it big performance issue ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I will try today to make regular auto-increment id and uuid for hide id from customer. I will share results it it fix a problem.